# c# setting relative path to other project

Tags: c#, relative-path, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to set a relative path to another project in the same solution.
I have a solution with 2 projects (projectA, projectB). The program starts with projectA, on a form of projectA there is a button "proceed to projectB". When clicked a form of projectB is opened. on this form I'm trying to load text files like this:

```
      inputStream = File.OpenText("textfile.txt");
            string line = inputStream.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                textBox1.AppendText(line);
                line = inputStream.ReadLine();
            }
```

The problem here is that I get an FileNotFoundExeption. Since the program looks for textfile.txt in projectA debug folder.

**C:\Users\ben\Documents\Project\projectA\bin\Debug**

But the textfile is actually located in the projectB debugfolder.

**C:\Users\ben\Documents\Project\projectB\bin\Debug**

How can I change the path so that the program searches in projectB debug folder?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make both projects output their binaries in a common folder?

C:\MyFolder\Project A -> C:\MyFolder\Output

C:\My Folder\Project B -> C:\MyFolder\Output

This way the above code will work.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? I have no idea what you are talking about sorry :/

Comment: set outdir on each of your csproj to be the same

Comment: ideally you would have started with an empty solution and added two projects -> this would cause your solution to have a common outdir

Comment: Yeah I understand but it is not the output I need. It is the input? I need the projectB to search for textfiles in it's own debug folder , not in projectA debug folder..